# Type declaration in Julia for function argument that can be both array and scalar

Tags: julia, type-declaration

What type should I specify in Julia for function arguments that can be either scalars or arrays? For instance, in the function below `x` and `y` could be e.g. `Float64` or `Array{Float64}`.

```
function myfun(x, y)
    return x .+ y
end
```

Is there an appropriate type declaration for such variables? Or should I just refrain from declaring the type there (or writing functions that are that generic)?

Comment: You should normally not write your functions to work on both scalars and collections. Instead create the function for scalars, then _call_ it with a dot: `myfun.(x, y)`. 'Auto-vectorized' functions are mildly discouraged in Julia. Virtually always, the person writing the code will know (or should know) whether a scalar or collection is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely refrain from specifying types. This will not have an impact on performance of your code.

However, if you want to explicitly specify the type restriction you provided do (this is mostly useful to make sure your function is called with proper arguments and fail fast if it is not):

```
function myfun(x::Union{Float64, Array{Float64}},
               y::Union{Float64, Array{Float64}})
    return x .+ y
end
```

However, most likely you will rather want the following signature:

```
function myfun(x::Union{AbstractFloat, AbstractArray{<:AbstractFloat}},
               y::Union{AbstractFloat, AbstractArray{<:AbstractFloat}})
    return x .+ y
end
```

which says you accept any scalar float or any array of floats (not necessarily only `Float64` and `Array`). This is more flexible, as e.g. you can accept views then or other floats (`BigFloat` or `Float32`) if you prefer to switch precision of your computations. Such a signature clearly signals your users what types of inputs you expect them to pass to `myfun` while remaining flexible.

I recommend this as being overly restrictive (`Union{Float64, Array{Float64}}`), while accepted by the compiler, usually leads to problems later when you start using your function with various input types.

Comment: Incidentally - I have just opened an issue whose root cause is exactly the topic I have discussed in my answer https://github.com/davidavdav/ROCAnalysis.jl/issues/25.